# purge-local-repository is not able to re-resolve dependencies after purge

Tags: maven, include, maven-dependency-plugin

I need to get the dependency for one artifact from remote repository instead of local(to get latest updates for the same version).

So I tried to use purge-local-repository. It is downloading first, then purging the local repo, but not able to re-resolve the dependency. It is trying to find the dependency/artifact only in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, but not in other remote repositories. The error message shows our repository(http://lxomavmpc110.qintra.com:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/Hyperion/content) in the list of "remote repositories" though.

Here is the plugin from pom.xml and the build log. Am I doing anything wrong or is there a bug?

```
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>purge-local-dependencies</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>purge-local-repository</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <include>com.xx.pojos:bmp-pojo-module</include>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

```
[INFO] Downloading from : http://lxomavmpc110.qintra.com:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/Hyperion/content/com/xx/pojos/bmp-pojo-module/1.0.0/bmp-pojo-module-1.0.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from : http://lxomavmpc110.qintra.com:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/Hyperion/content/com/xx/pojos/bmp-pojo-module/1.0.0/bmp-pojo-module-1.0.0.pom (3.9 kB at 11 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from : http://lxomavmpc110.qintra.com:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/Hyperion/content/com/xx/pojos/bmp-pojo-module/1.0.0/bmp-pojo-module-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from : http://lxomavmpc110.qintra.com:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/Hyperion/content/com/xx/pojos/bmp-pojo-module/1.0.0/bmp-pojo-module-1.0.0.jar (935 kB at 942 kB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:prepare-agent (default) @ order-process ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\AC01305\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.7.201606060606\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.7.201606060606-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\AC01305\\git\\order-checkout-process-2\\target\\jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:purge-local-repository (purge-local-dependencies) @ order-process ---
[WARNING] Failure to transfer net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml from http://maven.springframework.org/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml from/to spring-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release): Access denied to http://maven.springframework.org/release/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml. Error code 403, Forbidden
[WARNING] Failure to transfer net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven_central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven_central (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/): repo2.maven.org
[INFO] Purging dependencies for project: com.xx.process:order-process:jar:4.0.52
[INFO] Purging artifact: com.xx.pojos:bmp-pojo-module:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] Deleting: C:\Users\AC01305\.m2\repository\com\xx\pojos\bmp-pojo-module\1.0.0
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/xx/pojos/bmp-pojo-module/1.0.0/bmp-pojo-module-1.0.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.xx.pojos:bmp-pojo-module:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/xx/pojos/bmp-pojo-module/1.0.0/bmp-pojo-module-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Could not find artifact com.xx.pojos:bmp-pojo-module:jar:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
[INFO] Resolving artifact: com.xx.pojos:bmp-pojo-module:jar:1.0.0
[WARNING] The POM for com.xx.pojos:bmp-pojo-module:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Failure to find com.xx.pojos:bmp-pojo-module:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45.911 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-03T10:40:18-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:purge-local-repository (purge-local-dependencies) on project order-process: Failed to refresh project dependencies for: com.xx.process:order-process:jar:4.0.52: required artifacts missing:
[ERROR]   com.xx.pojos:bmp-pojo-module:jar:1.0.0
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] for the artifact:
[ERROR]   com.xx.process:order-process:jar:4.0.52
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]   hyperion (http://lxomavmpc110.qintra.com:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/Hyperion/content, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   corp.nexus.dev (http://lxomavmpc110.qintra.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/test, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   corp.nexus.thirdparty (http://lxomavmpc110.qintra.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   corp.nexus.snapshots (http://lxomavmpc110.qintra.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   spring-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   maven_central (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been banging my head against the wall for about a week because of the same issue, only with a different remote repository (re-resolve seems to work properly with the central repository).

I can't say if we both are missing something here or if there is indeed a bug. Anyway, I managed to find a workaround (to get the latest updates of an artifact with the same version).

So my workaround is to disable re-resolve on "purge-local-repository" goal and instead, add another execution of maven-dependency-plugin, but with the "get" goal.

For example, the pom.xml above should be modified more or less as follows (please notice I added "reResolve" tag with value "false" to the first execution and appended a new execution for the "get" goal right after it).

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>purge-local-dependencies</id>
      <phase>process-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>purge-local-repository</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <include>com.xx.pojos:bmp-pojo-module</include>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <reResolve>false</reResolve>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>get-remote-dependency</id>
      <phase>process-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>get</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <groupId>com.xx.pojos</groupId>
        <artifactId>bmp-pojo-module</artifactId>
        <version>[?.?.?]</version>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```